# How can I get/create the request structure from Soap service?

Tags: c#, soap

I have the wsdl of a web soap service and I have added it as a service reference with visual studio. I have notice that it doesn't have a request class for a method which I need to use. The reason I need it is because I have to store that request as xml and I have always used the request class to serialize. Is there a way to generate that request xml?
Simple representation:

```
var client = new SoapServiceCliente();
var request = new RequestClass(); <-- This is what soap service is missing.
var response = new ResponseClass();
response = client.theMethod(request);
```

Before calling the method I serialize the request to xml and after getting the response I serialize it too.

Comment: are you sure that types are exposed in the wsdl? is that public endpoint that you can share ?

Comment: @HanyHabib its private, work service. wsdl shows it like this:

`<xs:element name="theMethod">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="variable1" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="variable2" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>`